# Spivak Chapter 1 Problem 5 (x)

Tags: calculus

I am asking this not so much to get the "right" answer, but more to understand the approach and thinking that the seasoned mathematicians of this board follow.
So, the problem

> If $a,b \geq 0$ and ${a}^{2} < {b}^{2}$ then $a < b$. (Use (ix) backwards)

As a reminder, (ix) asks

> If $0 \leq a < b$ then ${a}^{2} <{b}^{2}$ (Use (viii))

As a commenter once noted with Spivak, he leans quite heavily on previously proven problems ( which are probably axioms important to future use).

So the proof to this problem ( from Spivak's answer book) says

> If $a < b$ were false, then either $a=b$ or $a>b$. But if $a=b$ then $a^{2} = b^{2}$ and if $a > b \geq 0$ then $a^{2} > b^{2} $ by part (ix)

So, here are my two questions.
(1) What part of that proof is the "**backwards**" part?
(2) Is it common to use a false assumption as a proof? (Or perhaps this is part of the "backwards" part).
I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: As to your second question, the idea is that Spivak is either using a proof-by-contradiction (assume the negation of the statement and derive a contradiction, hence showing that the original assumption was wrong) or proving the contrapositive of the statement (i.e. proving "(not-B) implies (not-A)" instead of "A implies B", because these are logically equivalent statements).

Comment: @march  So, it seems this approach would be especially useful for a problem with a limited number of outcomes, especially if a number of those outcomes has previously been proven?  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: There is a nuance here.  Normally, the statement $\{P \implies Q\}$ does not imply $\{Q \implies P\}$, since the 2nd statement is the converse of the 1st.  So, it is easy to overlook that you don't have to prove the stated problem from *scratch*.  Instead, you can use symmetry considerations around the two inequalities $a < b$ and $b < a$ to show that problem (ix) can be used to prove its **own** converse.  There is a separate unspoken lesson here.   Always try to avoid re-inventing the wheel, if possible.  That is, try to use *recent* previous results to prove posed questions.

Comment: @user2661923 Aha!! I think I get it. Spivak clearly states that for two numbers $a$, and $b$ only one will apply. ie $a = b$, $a<b$ for $b < a$. So, I guess the nuance ( and perhaps his "backwards" comment) refers to the fact that, as you implied, two of those options have been proven (but do not apply here), thus leaving only one ( the one is being asked to prove) as proven. Not too eloquently stated, but I hope understands the point you made. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, the more important lesson is contained in the last two sentences of my previous comment.

Comment: @user2661923 I am sorry if I did not imply that I noted your last two sentences and thought I had addressed your points, perhaps without directly saying so,  with thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Prove that if $a,b \geq 0$ and ${a}^{2} < {b}^{2},$ then $a < b.$   (Use (ix) **backwards**)
> >
> > (ix):    If $0 \leq a < b,$ then ${a}^{2} <{b}^{2}$
>
> Spivak's proof to this problem (from  answer book) says
>
> > If $a < b$ were false, then either $a=b$ or $a>b.$
> >
> > But if $a=b$ then $a^{2} = b^{2},$ and if $a > b \geq 0$ then $a^{2} > b^{2} $ by part (ix).
>
> Which part of that proof is the "**backwards**" part?

Spivak's proof simply takes cases and derives a contradiction by using (ix)—forwards, not backwards.

Here's a clearer proof, also invoking (ix), that actually does involve working backwards (note that $P\Rightarrow Q\equiv$ (not $P$) or $Q):$

- We want to show that  \begin{align}a \geq b\implies
     \text{not}\,\big(a,b \geq 0\;\text{and}\;a^2 < b^2\big),\end{align} which is equivalent to each of the following \begin{align}a
     < b\quad\text{or}\quad \big(a<0\quad\text{or}\quad b<0\quad\text{or}\quad a^2 \geq
     b^2\big)\\\text{not}\,\big(a > b\quad\text{and}\quad a>0\quad\text{and}\quad b>0 \big)\quad\text{or}\quad a^2 \geq b^2 \\0<b<a\implies a^2
     \geq b^2
  \\0<a<b\implies a^2
     \leq b^2.\tag{*}\end{align}

  $(*)$ is a consequence of $$0<a<b\implies a^2< b^2,$$ which is an immediate consequence of (ix).

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain where did the "or" came from in line 2? I see that P ==> Q means not P or Q, but I don't understand.

Comment: @Fernando Thanks for noticing the mistake! I've just changed the answer.